# Issue with renaming of a column in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have this piece of code. I am trying to rename two columns in a dataframe (df) where the name is dependent on some prior conditions. I used df.rename but the name in the column does not change to what is meant to be renamed (for example Attrib1).  I know the condition in the IF statement is met but I get an error message for the self.df.rename which says:

```
unhashable type: 'list'
```

I thought the variable heading_contain_name1 needs to be a string so did  the variable with and without str(heading_contain_name1) but none of them replaced the column name.

I am using Python 2.7 and cannot change to higher version (at least for the next few months).  Any help is appreciated.

```
if "name1" or "name2" in map(str.upper,list(self.df)): 
    name1_expres=re.compile("manager", re.IGNORECASE)
    name2_expres=re.compile("admin", re.IGNORECASE)
    heading_contain_name1=filter(name1_expres.search, list(self.df))
    heading_contain_name2=filter(name2_expres.search, list(self.df))                
    self.Application_CBox.addItems(heading_contain_name1) 
    self.Application_CBox.addItems(heading_contain_name2) 
    self.df.rename(columns={str(heading_contain_name1): 'Attrib1', 
                             str(heading_contain_name2): 'Attrib2'},inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note the below statement will *always* return `True`:

```
if "name1" or "name2" in map(str.upper,list(self.df)):
```

This is because the express is evaluated as:

```
if ("name1") or ("name2" in map(str.upper, list(self.df))):
```

Since the first condition is always `True` (try `bool('name1')` to satisfy yourself this is the case), the `or` condition will always return `True`.

Second, note that `filter` returns a list in Python 2.7, and regex seems overkill for what you are trying to achieve.

This is more likely what you are looking to do:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
cols = df.columns

if any(i in cols for i in ('name1', 'name2')):
    name1 = next(i for i in cols if 'manager' in i)
    name2 = next(i for i in cols if 'admin' in i)
    self.df = self.df.rename(columns={name1: 'Attrib1', name2: 'Attrib2'})
```

Comment: Thanks. The answer worked very nicely.  With your explanation I see what the problem was.